# number theory problem, about arctan and pi

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry, gaussian-integers

I have encountered a problem, that is:

Find all integers $a,b,c,d$, so that
$$ \frac{\pi}{4}=a\arctan\left(\frac1b\right)+c\arctan\left(\frac1d\right). $$

Is it possible to find all solutions satisfying the upper equation?

the equation is equivalent to $(b+i)^a(d+i)^c=r(1+i)$, which $r$ some unknown integers.
Using the theory of Gaussian Integers, and define $N(x+yi)=x^2+y^2$, so $N(\alpha\beta)=N(\alpha)N(\beta)$, for $N(1+i)$ is prime number, so $1+i$ is prime in Gaussian, all these result is fundamental. so there must be $(1+i)\mid(b+i)$ or $(1+i)\mid(d+i)$.
but this conclusion is not sufficient to get $(b+i)^a(d+i)^c$ have the same real part and imaginary part. so... any help?

Comment: Look up [Machin's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machin-like_formula).

Comment: yes, thanks for your comment, but Størmer's paper was not written in English, difficult to understand... :(

Comment: As uneasy as it may seem, try to use some dictionaries that you may find online or elsewhere ([this](http://bibmath.net/trans/index.php?action=recherche&francais=&langue=English) for instance). Many relevant yet too specific French articles have not been translated. It may be useful to learn the basics of French mathematical jargon depending on how much math you plan on studying later on. Of course, that is demanding so it is for you to decide.